Google Cloud Build Errors Finding Dockerfile
I'm a Docker/Cloud Build noob.
The build section (Step 2) of my cloudbuild.yml file is pretty much straight out of the examples:
  # Docker Build
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    id: Docker Build
    args: [
      "build",
      "--tag",
      "us-kata9-docker.pkg.dev/<project>/<repo>/<image>:latest",
      # "--file=/workspace/Dockerfile",
      ".",
    ]

The step fails with:
Starting Step #2 - "Docker Build"
Step #2 - "Docker Build": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Step #2 - "Docker Build": unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /workspace/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
Finished Step #2 - "Docker Build"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

BUILD FAILURE: Build step failure: build step 2 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) build br-549 completed with status "FAILURE"

I have tried specifying the path using the --file switch (see commented bit in yaml snippet above) and putting the path /workspace as the positional argument.
Here's where the noob aspect rears it's head: I really don't know whether my error is my fault or not. Am I meant to somehow provide a Dockerfile to Cloud Build? From what I understand, cloudbuild.yaml handles everything for the process of building and deploying an image. I expected no other configuration or scripts outside of cloudbuild.yaml to be required. I have already deployed my python packages to the "Artifact Registry (which the preceeding steps seem to find with no problem.)

Yep, you need to provide a Dockerfile since your trying to build a container image. Cloud Build is a building system and you define steps to build YOUR sources, it won't automagically create a Dockerfile or extra needed files for you to make things work. If you're a noob as you say, then start by understanding Containers and build them in your local machine instead of jumping directly to Build Systems in the cloud. On the other hand gcp offers some tutorials to start with CB, read them

Is your Python app straightforward? If so, we could probably help you with a Dockerfile to get you through this step. Please update your question with a synopsis. Is it something like hello-world? NB There is a concept of buildpacks which means that you don't always have to write a Dockerfile in order to containerize an app.

@Puteri I have built, tested, and run a container locally using a Dockerfile with this exact module earlier. The reason I started using Google Cloud Build is that it was unclear to me how to test my scripts locally using Docker. I am, as you suggested, using the Cloud Build tutorials. I still don't see anything in the tutorials specifying how to provide a Dockerfile to Cloud build. It does seem kind of redundant: I'm going through all the same steps in my cloudbuild.yaml that I did in my original Dockerfile. I'll try creating a new Dockerfile using /workspace as my WORKDIR.

@DazWilkin the python script is built as a package and stored in Google Artifact Registry. The package has console_scripts to provide a command-line interface for the modules in the package. I have successfuly built a container and run it both interactively and by using the CMD directory from within the Dockerfile. Sorry if I was not clear about my real issue. My understanding of how Cloud Build relates to Docker has been clouded by the way cloudbuild.yml seems to do exactly what the Docker file does!

@DazWilkin the above should have read "I have successfuly built a container and run the modules both interactively and by using the CMD directory from within the Dockerfile." Tried to edit it, but apparently I took >5 minutes to write my reply! :)

@DazWilkin @Puteri, the reason I switched my focus to using Google Cloud build was due to difficulties figuring out how to provide various keys and credentials to the Dockerfile as setting environment variables can be a bit confusing. Cloud Build seemed to provide cleaner methods: availableSecrets and secretEnv.

Cloud Build will (by default) look for Dockerfile in the root directory (usually alongside cloudbuild.yaml) of the folder from which gcloud builds submit is run.
